# Python, unusual behaviour with hidden directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a python script to set my Ubuntu-gnome desktop wallpaper from bing.com .

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import urllib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

imageurl='http://www.bing.com'
page=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-IN/')
xml=page.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,'xml')
imageurl += soup.url.string
imageurl=imageurl[:-12]+'1920x1080.jpg'
print imageurl
try:
    urllib.urlretrieve(imageurl, "wallpaper1.jpg")
    if os.path.isfile('wallpaper.jpg'):
        os.remove('wallpaper.jpg')
    os.rename('wallpaper1.jpg','wallpaper.jpg')
except Exception as e:
    pass
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper.jpg")
```

My script works perfectly fine when I was running it from a normal directory, but when I used the same script after copying it to a hidden directory (/home/sumit/.myscripts) it gave error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumit/.myscripts/bing.py", line 18, in <module>
    os.rename('/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper1.jpg','/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper.jpg')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

And image didn't got downloaded. But it worked when I replaced path at each place with absolute path.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import urllib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

imageurl='http://www.bing.com'
page=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-IN/')
xml=page.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,'xml')
imageurl += soup.url.string
imageurl=imageurl[:-12]+'1920x1080.jpg'
print imageurl
try:
    urllib.urlretrieve(imageurl, "/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper1.jpg")
    if os.path.isfile('/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper.jpg'):
        os.remove('/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper.jpg')
    os.rename('/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper1.jpg','/home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper.jpg')
except Exception as e:
    print 'Unable to download'
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/sumit/.myscripts/wallpaper.jpg")
```

I am confused about this behaviour. It would be very helpful if somebody can explain me whats going on as I am new to python.

Comment: one thing I'm not getting: the stacktrace shows the code using absolute paths, which you said it worked... BTW you should try `shutil.move` instead of delete+rename. It does exactly that.